# When will I be able to vote again on outdated answers?

Tags: discussion, outdated-answer

I've just voted for an outdated answer, and got the following message:

[image]

When will it be eligible for my vote again? It could be that in a few weeks/months it will eventually become outdated.

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, it's 1 in 1000 people that get to see it; it's not a case of "when" you'll see it, but "if". I've never seen it personally.

Comment: @Larnu Interesting. Is it based on someone's contribution to specific topics?

Comment: Apparently it's 1 in 100, not 1 in 1,000 (as 1% of views see it).

Comment: Yay, I'm 1 in 100! That must mean I'm special! (Of course, *really* special would be a way to opt out of seeing emojis on the page..)

Comment: @Larnu Close your browser and open it up again. It's easy to get the right session

Comment: I'm, in truth, not bothered enough about it at the moment, @Dharman . I'm happy to wait until I am able to properly contribute when my actions mean something and move answers down the page because they are outdated/dangerous.

Comment: @Larnu Did you know that you can already do precisely that by *downvoting* the post? (Yes, I know you knew that.)

Comment: I already downvote them @CodyGray, I meant that I see no point in closing and opening my browser over and over to play the gacha game of getting to mark it out of date :)

Comment: I'm not sure that outdated answers should be downvoted (unless they're harmful of course).

Comment: Seems that answers which give outdated advice could qualify as being harmful. Unless they're on a question with a version-specific tag, of course.

Comment: I qgree, but I was talking about outdated answer in the sense of "a newer version of that framework is available", which still 100% correct. This brings me to the question: How exactly we define an "outdated" answer?